# UNIX email with multiple attachments and encryption

Tags: email, unix, encryption, openssl

Is there a way (preferably a simple, concise way) to send an email from the command line in UNIX with multiple encrypted attachments?

This is in a workplace environment, so I am hesitant to install anything.

Comment: What did you have in mind for encryption? GnuPG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line tool `openssl` is usually already installed on most UNIX-like servers.  It is something of a cryptographic swiss-army knife; its [`openssl smime`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html) utility allows you to create S/MIME standard encrypted and/or signed mail.

Comment: I did some research and this fits my needs best.  Thanks!

Comment: @dpatchery can you please post your research results please?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have two encrypted files file1.pgp  file2.pgp  (edit: uuencode -> uuencode -m)

Tar and mail them

```
tar cf -  file1.pgp  file2.pgp | uuencode -m myfile.tar | mailx -s 'test'  me@mycomputer.com
```

The recipient will need something to open the tar container: windows 7zip, etc.  You can also zip the files.  gzip will not work.

```
echo "file1.pgp file2.pgp" | zip zipfilename -@ 
cat zipfilename.zip | uunecode -m zipfilename.zip | mailx -s 'test' me@mycomputer.com
```

If the files are not encrypted you can encrypt and password protect with zip

```
echo "file1.txt file2.txt" | zip zipfilename -@  -P password
```

This is not secure in the sense that some can see you enter the password with the ps command on the unix box.

edit: Dec 26120120

Comment: gzip is fine, but it is not an archiver, it only works with one file.

Comment: Using 'uuencode' is unusual and not entirely robust - one reason why Base-64 was invented and is widely used in emails.  In particular, it can end lines with spaces, and spaces could, conceivably be dropped at the ends of lines (though that was more of a problem 20 years ago than it is today).

Comment: Unfortunately the version of zip my company uses does not support encryption.

Comment: crypt is part of standard distributions  You can use it to encrypt either the tar ball or each file in a tarball.  It is not as secure as pgp.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to offer this as an answer because it’s as old as Moses and probably even more out of date, but I use the [nmh](http://rand-mh.sourceforge.net/book/mh/confmhn.html) system of commands for this sort of thing.

It’s incredibly abstruse, but you can build most anything you want out of it. It might even already be installed on your system, which I suspect would be a benefit.

I have no doubt there are infinitely many newer, slicker, hipper, and more wonderful systems out there for this sort of thing.  I just don’t know them.  I’ve got some 25 years worth of accumulated email that I access under this system, and I’ve written dozens of applications on top of it for customized little approaches.

I still answer mail using `vi` to edit, and I read mail in a Terminal window.  I still have scripts around I used from back before `perl` was even invented.  That’s how ancient this is. I first started using it in early or mid-80s.  I can’t remember anything before it except perhaps `/usr/ucb/Mail`. It would be easy to write an `sh` or `perl` script that glues together MH commands to do exactly what you’re asking for.

I wouldn’t wish MH on anybody else, though. My mom manages to cope with it, but she’s a `vi` user herself and has studied more assembly language than I have.  Beyond her, I don’t know if I can count a half-dozen friends who still use MH for their mail.

It does have one thing going for it, though: you’ll never, ever, *ever* get spoofed by anybody trying to dupe you into falling for a phishing exploit, because you always eyeball even HTML mail as plaintext initially (at least that’s how I have it set up), so you immediately see that the links are wacky.